# Load Variables from (Javascript) .js file using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

New to PHP so apologies in advance for the simple question.

I have a Javascript file (.js). which contains a list of values. i.e.

```
var item1 = 1.00;
var item2 = 25.00;
var item2 = 35.00;
```

Can can i use PHP to read this file and import the data in an array with values.

```
item1 = 1.00  
item2 = 25.00    
item2 = 35.00
```

and then I would like to be able to GET the PHP script with.
xyz.com/file.php?id=item1.
and be able to send back the associated value.

I now this is simple, but i am having very little success as to where to start.  I reviewed  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php.  but I think it it needs the file to be read to have .ini extension which is not an option in my situation.

Any help,guidance,advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're probably going to need to write a custom parser.

Comment: I agree with the custom parser option. Although, if the file only contains values, saving it as a JSON file could help both ways, either PHP and JS

Comment: Maybe help this project of fully JS parser in PHP: https://github.com/mck89/peast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would create array from variables
2. Loop through array to create inputs
3. Put array values into input values
4. Submit form to PHP

```js
var item1 = 1.00;
var item2 = 25.00;
var item3 = 35.00; 

let array = [];

array.push(item1)
array.push(item2)
array.push(item3)

let inputs = ``;
for(let i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++){
    inputs += `
    <div>
        <input type="text" value='${array[i]}' />
    </div>
  `
}

document.getElementById("inputs-here").innerHTML = inputs;
```

```html
<form method="post" action="your-route-here">
  <div id="inputs-here"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and after you can capture it in PHP, just try this and you can take from there

```
print_r($_POST)
```

You can also create these inputs as "hidden" and submit without button, using JavaScript automatically, but that's different subject.